# Freebase image URLs -- which is it?

Tags: google-api, freebase

The documentation (https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-response#references-to-image-objects) says it is `https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/...`

However, the `freebase.com` web site creates links to images using the following URL:
`https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/...`

(one is `usercontent.googleapis.com` while the other is `www.googleapis.com`)

Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the intent is to move to using the `https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/...` form as a way of signalling to apps/users that it's potentially untrusted content.  Ditto for text blurbs.